# Iterating with for loop through variables

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm fairly new to coding. I'm trying to iterate the variable k through my function and store the results in a list. k starts with k=1 and ends with k=40. But something isnt working. My list only contains 0s. Hopefully you can help me

[Here is a Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzcBp.png)

[Here is another attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPK2V.png)

```py
Tn = []
for k in range(1, 40):
    x = ((40+0.2) / ((k-0.4))* (17/40))
    Tn.append(x)
    
print Tn
```

Comment: Are you using python 2? No parenthesis in ```print x```

Comment: I'm sorry. but `something isnt working` is neither a question nor an explanation. Please be more specific. Are you seeing an error? Are you seeing output that you weren't expecting?

Comment: My list is only containing 0s, which is incorrect.

Comment: Ok, I see you have posted the text of some code. When I try to run this I end up with a list of non-zero numbers. (The first of which is ~28.47)

Comment: 28.47 would be correct for k=1. Mh, then I dont know why I am not getting that.

Comment: okay, so this works when I write it like this x = ((40.+0.2) / ((k-0.4))* (17./40.)) But I dont know why I would need to put a point behind the numbers.

Comment: Perhaps you should upgrade to python 3

Comment: For the moment I have to use 2.7 because its installed on our university pcs and we are not allowed to install anything.

Comment: @Neihilrach I would like to inform you that Python2 has reached end-of-life and If you continue to learn using Python2 in your university, You might have problems while accounting for a job. Correct me if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Your k variable is a range object, not an index.

Try putting your variable inside a list, and then iterate through that list. You don't even have to use the range object to iterate through a list :

```py
lst = [10, 20, 30, 40]

for item in lst:
    print(item) # print item if you use Python 2
```

And if you want to use an index :

```py
for index in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[index]) # print lst[index] if you use Python 2
```

If you want to use variables :

```py
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30
d = 40
lst = [a, b, c, d]

for item in lst:
    print(item) # print item if you use Python 2
```

Side note : you seem to be using Python 2. I would highly recommend you use Python 3.x (the latest the version the better). The transition is not difficult at all, and even easier if you're new to coding. Python 3.x has way more to offer than Python 2 and you will quickly see its limitations.

Comment: For the moment I have to use 2.7 because its installed on our university pcs and we are not allowed to install anything lol.

Comment: Your university won't allow Python 3? What course are you taking ? Is it focused on Python or is it more of an algorithmic course ? If the goal is to learn Python then not using Python 3 is a mistake.

Comment: I guess when you are studying IT, which I dont, then its probably no problem. It would take a while to explain my situation. Basicaly I have to use whats already there because other people wrote code in 2.7 and no one ever bothered to transform that into 3. I actually was told at some point that "this wouldnt work in 3". It it what it is.

Comment: Well I'm sorry for this, this situation really sucks. I don't know anybody who uses Python 2 nowadays. It's like using Windows 95 or Internet Explorer.